# Network share (not shared folder) inaccessible from Ubuntu VirtualBox virtual machine vm to Windows

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, sharing

I've installed a Ubuntu 22.10 virtual machine on VirtualBox 7.0.4 running on Windows 10. I've also made a network share using **nautilus-share** extension.

This is not a shared folders problem, since shared folders are working just fine. It is a network share issue. On Windows, when I try and access the network share, Windows complais saying `I'm not allowed access for lack of permissions`.

The point is that this type of sharing was working well on VirtualBox 6.1 with Ubuntu 22.04. Also, searching the Internet I
noticed that other people can pretty much straight forward make network shares using nautilus-share extension.

It seems to me as if some compatibility between VirtualBox and Windows got broken, but the fact is that I cannot tell for sure what is happening. Could someone be kind to unlock this problem?

I've tried to reinstall everything from scratch, even formatting Windows 10 for that matter. In the end, It made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier (much easier) to get from Ubuntu to Windows.

(1) Make sure in Windows that Network Discovery, File and Print Share and Password Protected access are all ON.  Restart the host if you change anything here.

(2) Once ready, in Ubuntu, in the GUI Folder App:

smb://192.168.x.y/shared folder  (check IP of host machine)

I use this method for both Ubuntu and Kali VMs to map a folder on my Windows 11 Host.  Works great.

If you wish to map from Windows to Ubuntu, install Samba on Ubuntu and configure it.

[Set up Samba](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba)

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to restablish network share access by means of editing `/etc/samba/smb.conf` via **sudo nano** and adding

`usershare owner only = false`

just below the line

`usershare allow guests = yes`.

I am still doing the share through nautilus-share extension and the other settings remain the same.

Strangely enough, anyways nautilus-share extension even rewrites the permissions of my network share as root and gives an error message in the end saying it `could no change the required permissions`

Comment: There are other changes to Samba Config that can make standard file sharing permanent.  I have the Samba tutorial in my answer.  I use Windows to Ubuntu via Samba myself although I prefer the simpler share from Ubuntu to Windows.

Comment: Many thanks to you, John, for your contribution. On my part, I need to do the sharing from Ubuntu side, since Windows file system doesn't handle Linux symbolic links, which I cannot avoid in my setup.

Comment: I showed how to map from Ubuntu to Windows.  Really easy to do and that is why I posted those details